# How to replace white spaces with %20 in folder names containing images?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm getting error in W3 Validator on my friends opencart page:

> Bad value http://myserver.com/cache/data/product/MY PRODUCT/product1-290x214.JPG for attribute src on element img: Whitespace in path component. Use %20 in place of spaces.

That indicates that user created folder with white spaces (MY PRODUCT).

Where code need to be modyfied to convert white spaces in folder names to %20?

Comment: [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Comment: Why not use [str_replace](http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to change spaces automatically to underscores or dash? Just a thought but then you wouldn't have to worry about anything

Comment: @Edga - That would just result in a 404 for the image path

Comment: Yes but it was just a question&suggestion wherever the dir is being created, to actually perform str_replace, rather than worry about urls

Comment: In OpenCart images are everywhere. It wouldn't really be feasible IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

A simple [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) should do the trick if you have the full URL with you. Something like this:

```
echo str_replace(' ','%20',$full_link);
```

Otherwise, you may do as suggested by one commenter to use [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode). This is useful if you have a path to the site already and are just adding something like product name:

```
echo 'http://site.name/hello/'.urlencode($product);
```

Comment: I were looking for the place where code should be applied. Found temporary solution to replace spaces with %20 on the "Store Front". But still looking for better way of doing by modyfing Admin area...

Answer (score 2):

While `urlencode()` is the one you should be using, the thing you should do here is **educate your friend** into not doing this again, renaming it to have no space in it and updating the paths in  the database. If you want a solution that will rectify this in your cart across all pages in your cart, you could use `urlencode()` or `str_replace()` in your `/catalog/modl/tool/image.php` file

```
        $new_image = 'cache/' . utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $extension;
```

would need to be changed, either adding a line after it to add the `%20`, or editing that line to include it in one single line. Of course you should also do this in a vQmod not just edit your core files so that it will remain when your friend's site is updated to newer versions

### EDIT

If the above code isn't working for it, you could manipulate the returned URL's after they've been built directly. These are the two return lines (first for HTTPS images, second for HTTP)

```
        return HTTPS_IMAGE . $new_image;
    } else {
        return HTTP_IMAGE . $new_image;
```

Comment: I could find path `/catalog/model/tool/image.php` in my opencart. I found same code in `/admin/model/tool/image.php` and below that code I added: `$new_image=urlencode($new_image);` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: did you try a `str_replace`?

Comment: yes I did try but no difference. Are you sure this is the right place to put this code?

Comment: The code's not been tested but it should work. See my edit above. This is definitely the file you need to be editing unless the image output isn't actually being resized. If that is the case, you will need to edit the code in the controller of the page you are on to get this to work

Comment: Hi, The problem wasn't in the code you gave me but in the place where should be aplied. str_replace() did create product folders with %20 in the cache folder but all pleces where picture should be displayed still was reading from the folder without %20 in the name. I did managed to make this work by reverting changes in that file and editing every single file which display foto and replacing spaces there. I will treat that as a solution till will find better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart image resize model really returns image path with spaces, if You have such in folder names or image filenames.

Try to edit catalog/model/tool/image.php  last lines with rationalboss suggested workaround:

```
return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . str_replace(' ','%20', $new_image);
```

and

```
return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . str_replace(' ','%20', $new_image);
```

Opencart still uploads images with spaces, UTF-8 characters etc. I think, this must be fixed in next Opencart versions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to edit catalog/model/tool/image.php

```
    if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
        return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . str_replace(' ','%20', $new_image);
    } else {
        return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . str_replace(' ','%20', $new_image);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your /catalog/model/tool/image.php file after

```
$new_image = 'cache/' . utf8_substr($filename, 0, utf8_strrpos($filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . $type .'.' . $extension;
```

add

```
$new_image = implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $new_image)));
```